# flowtype, large number of dependencies on file change

Tags: javascript, flowtype

On our application we are using flow for typechecking, which is all good and fine, however there seems to be a very large amount of dependencies that need to be checked on each incremental pass of the type checker, a single change on a very leaf component generates the following output:

```
/Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast osp@DeepThought git:(oscar/ignore-firebase-functions-from-flow*)
cat /private/tmp/flow/zSUserszSospzSDeveloperzSbodyfast.log
[2020-11-18 13:21:15.219] argv=/Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/node_modules/flow-bin/flow-osx-v0.122.0/flow start --flowconfig-name .flowconfig --autostop --from vscode --temp-dir /tmp/flow /Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast
[2020-11-18 13:21:15.219] lazy_mode=off
[2020-11-18 13:21:15.219] arch=classic
[2020-11-18 13:21:15.219] abstract_locations=off
[2020-11-18 13:21:15.219] max_workers=16
[2020-11-18 13:21:15.245] Initializing Server (This might take some time)
[2020-11-18 13:21:15.245] executable=/Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/node_modules/flow-bin/flow-osx-v0.122.0/flow
[2020-11-18 13:21:15.245] version=0.122.0
[2020-11-18 13:21:15.245] No saved state available
[2020-11-18 13:21:15.253] Parsing
[2020-11-18 13:21:22.481] Building package heap
[2020-11-18 13:21:22.638] Loading libraries
[2020-11-18 13:21:24.527] Resolving dependencies
[2020-11-18 13:21:25.673] Resolved requires changed
[2020-11-18 13:21:26.118] to_merge: Focused: 1126, Dependents: 0, Dependencies: 370
[2020-11-18 13:21:26.118] Calculating dependencies
[2020-11-18 13:21:26.122] Merging
[2020-11-18 13:21:40.710] Merge skipped 0 of 1496 modules
[2020-11-18 13:21:40.713] Done
[2020-11-18 13:21:40.713] Checked set: Focused: 1126, Dependents: 0, Dependencies: 370
[2020-11-18 13:21:40.714] Server is READY
[2020-11-18 13:21:40.714] Took 25.469162 seconds to initialize.
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.294] Adding new persistent connection #1
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.294] Running a serial workload
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.294] Persistent request: subscribe
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.302] Subscribing client #1 to push diagnostics
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.302] Persistent response: lspFromServer None
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.302] Client #1 opened /Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.302] Running a serial workload
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.302] Persistent request: lspToServer textDocument/didOpen
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.302] Persistent response: lspFromServer None
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.302] Running a serial workload
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.302] Persistent request: liveErrorsRequest file:///Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
[2020-11-18 13:21:41.351] Persistent response: liveErrorsResponse OK (0 errors, 0 warnings) file:///Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
[2020-11-18 13:21:52.144] Running a serial workload
[2020-11-18 13:21:52.144] Persistent request: lspToServer textDocument/codeAction
[2020-11-18 13:21:52.153] Persistent response: lspFromServer textDocument/codeAction
[2020-11-18 13:21:52.154] Running a serial workload
[2020-11-18 13:21:52.154] Persistent request: lspToServer textDocument/typeCoverage
[2020-11-18 13:21:52.163] Persistent response: lspFromServer textDocument/typeCoverage
[2020-11-18 13:21:52.746] Running a serial workload
[2020-11-18 13:21:52.746] Persistent request: lspToServer textDocument/hover
[2020-11-18 13:21:52.750] Persistent response: lspFromServer textDocument/hover
[2020-11-18 13:21:55.020] Persistent request: lspToServer textDocument/didChange
[2020-11-18 13:21:55.021] Persistent response: lspFromServer None
[2020-11-18 13:21:55.021] Running a serial workload
[2020-11-18 13:21:55.021] Persistent request: liveErrorsRequest file:///Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
[2020-11-18 13:21:55.032] Persistent response: liveErrorsResponse OK (0 errors, 0 warnings) file:///Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
[2020-11-18 13:21:55.250] Running a serial workload
[2020-11-18 13:21:55.250] Persistent request: lspToServer textDocument/codeAction
[2020-11-18 13:21:55.260] Persistent response: lspFromServer textDocument/codeAction
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.189] Persistent request: lspToServer textDocument/didSave
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.189] Persistent response: lspFromServer None
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.193] Running a parallel workload
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.193] Persistent request: liveErrorsRequest file:///Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.203] Persistent response: liveErrorsResponse OK (0 errors, 0 warnings) file:///Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.203] Running a parallel workload
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.203] Persistent request: lspToServer textDocument/typeCoverage
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.213] Persistent response: lspFromServer textDocument/typeCoverage
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.213] recheck 1 modified, 0 deleted files
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.213] modified files:
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.213] 1/1: /Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.213] Parsing
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.230] Resolved requires are unchanged
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.248] Re-resolving directly dependent files
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.264] Resolved requires are unchanged
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.264] Recalculating dependency graph
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.305] recheck 386 dependent files:
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.305] to_merge: Focused: 1, Dependents: 385, Dependencies: 0
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.305] Calculating dependencies
[2020-11-18 13:21:56.307] Merging
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling since a recheck is needed
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 1/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 2/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 3/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 4/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 5/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 6/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 7/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 8/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 9/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 10/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 11/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 12/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 13/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 14/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 15/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.166] Canceling progress 16/16
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.168] Recheck successfully canceled. Restarting the recheck to include new file changes
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.168] recheck 1 modified, 0 deleted files
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.168] modified files:
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.168] 1/1: /Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.168] Parsing
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.195] Resolved requires are unchanged
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.195] Re-resolving directly dependent files
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.210] Resolved requires are unchanged
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.210] Recalculating dependency graph
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.245] recheck 386 dependent files:
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.245] to_merge: Focused: 1, Dependents: 385, Dependencies: 0
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.246] Calculating dependencies
[2020-11-18 13:21:57.247] Merging
[2020-11-18 13:22:04.786] sending (0 errors) and (warnings from 1 files) to 1 subscribed clients (of 1 total)
[2020-11-18 13:22:05.040] sending (0 errors) and (warnings from 1 files) to 1 subscribed clients (of 1 total)
[2020-11-18 13:22:05.307] sending (0 errors) and (warnings from 1 files) to 1 subscribed clients (of 1 total)
[2020-11-18 13:22:05.905] sending (0 errors) and (warnings from 1 files) to 1 subscribed clients (of 1 total)
[2020-11-18 13:22:07.968] Merge skipped 0 of 386 modules
[2020-11-18 13:22:07.969] Done
[2020-11-18 13:22:07.970] Checked set: Focused: 1126, Dependents: 0, Dependencies: 370
[2020-11-18 13:22:07.976] sending (0 errors) and (warnings from 37 files) to 1 subscribed clients (of 1 total)
[2020-11-18 13:22:07.976] Running a serial workload
[2020-11-18 13:22:07.976] Persistent request: liveErrorsRequest file:///Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
[2020-11-18 13:22:08.043] Persistent response: liveErrorsResponse OK (0 errors, 0 warnings) file:///Users/osp/Developer/bodyfast/src/Containers/SettingsMealsScene.js
```

You can see I changed the SettingsMealsScene but this generates a recheck of 386(!) files and it takes 5 - 6 before I can see any type errors.

Is there anyway to see the generated dependency tree? could there be anything wrong with our flow configuration?

our `.flowconfig.js`:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/.*
.*/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/.*
.*/node_modules/@react-native-community/picker.*
.*/node_modules/@react-native-community/slider.*
# remove when flow is updated. Currently leads to "Cannot assign rest to restState because rest [1] is incompatible with State [2]."
.*/node_modules/redux-persist/lib/persistReducer.js.flow
.*/node_modules/recompose/dist/Recompose.cjs.js.flow
.*/firebase/**

; We fork some components by platform
.*/*[.]android.js

; Ignore "BUCK" generated dirs
<PROJECT_ROOT>/\.buckd/

; Ignore polyfills
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/polyfills/.*

; These should not be required directly
; require from fbjs/lib instead: require('fbjs/lib/warning')
node_modules/warning/.*

; Flow doesn't support platforms
.*/Libraries/Utilities/LoadingView.js

[untyped]
.*/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/.*/.*
.*/node_modules/react-native-confetti-cannon/.*
.*/node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/.*

[libs]
node_modules/react-native/interface.js
node_modules/react-native/flow/
flow/libs

[options]
emoji=true

esproposal.optional_chaining=enable
esproposal.nullish_coalescing=enable
module.file_ext=.js
module.file_ext=.json
module.file_ext=.ios.js
module.system.node.allow_root_relative=true
munge_underscores=true
module.name_mapper='^react-native/\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/react-native/\1'
module.name_mapper='^@?[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.\(bmp\|gif\|jpg\|jpeg\|png\|psd\|svg\|webp\|m4v\|mov\|mp4\|mpeg\|mpg\|webm\|aac\|aiff\|caf\|m4a\|mp3\|wav\|html\|pdf\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RelativeImageStub'
module.name_mapper.extension='svg' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow/SVGFlowStub.js'

suppress_type=$FlowIssue
suppress_type=$FlowFixMe
suppress_type=$FlowFixMeProps
suppress_type=$FlowFixMeState

suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixMe\\($\\|[^(]\\|(\\(<VERSION>\\)? *\\(site=[a-z,_]*react_native\\(_ios\\)?_\\(oss\\|fb\\)[a-z,_]*\\)?)\\)
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowIssue\\((\\(<VERSION>\\)? *\\(site=[a-z,_]*react_native\\(_ios\\)?_\\(oss\\|fb\\)[a-z,_]*\\)?)\\)?:? #[0-9]+
suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowExpectedError

[lints]
sketchy-null-number=warn
sketchy-null-mixed=warn
sketchy-number=warn
untyped-type-import=warn
nonstrict-import=warn
deprecated-type=warn
unsafe-getters-setters=warn
unnecessary-invariant=warn
signature-verification-failure=warn
deprecated-utility=error

[strict]
deprecated-type
nonstrict-import
sketchy-null
unclear-type
unsafe-getters-setters
untyped-import
untyped-type-import

[version]
^0.122.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try upgrading Flow to v0.133 and switch to the [Types-First](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/types-first/) architecture, or enable it on earlier releases. The rechecks have considerably improved, as explained, since all module exports are now annotated instead of being infered. There is [a codemod availble](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/types-first/#toc-a-codemod-for-large-codebases) for annotating exports on large codebases:

```
yarn flow codemod --help
```

If you're still concerned about performances, you might want to probe for expensive cycles, exported types that are shared between modules and re-exported from them, which keep getting refined as new modules are parsed. I am offering this from practical past experience, though I don't know how relevant it is in newer releases: visualize the dependency graph from modules that are causing slow rechecks and try to resolve cycles by moving the related code/types to independent modules:

```
yarn flow cycle --strip-root --types path/to/module.js | dot -Tpng > cycle.png
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with more or less the same answer, flow needs to be updated and we can turn on the performance improvements, however, this is impossible at the moment, since our flow version is tied to react-native, maybe in the future, thanks though!

Comment: @Oscar maintaining Flow server version parity with an upstream repo is certainly a good thing. You could configure `react-native` to your [declarations](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/declarations/#toc-declarations) section--this will still allow you to use types and module signatures, but it willl not report any errors, which could allow you to move ahead of what version of Flow `react-native` is using.

Comment: Hey, I'm revisiting this problem and trying to execute the flow cycle command you posted, but it doesn't seem to be working with flow version ^0.137.0